# Why can't JavaFX find my .fxml controller file?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, gluon

Just started with JavaFX and I have an issue.
When I start my project from [here](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Darknet-Data-Creator) with the command `mvn javafx:run` then I got this error.

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name se.danielmartensson.controller.maincontroller, locale sv_SE
    at se.danielmartensson.Main.start(Main.java:42)
```

Which is this code line:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("controller/maincontroller.fxml"), ResourceBundle.getBundle("se.danielmartensson.controller.maincontroller")); // <--- THIS
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have placed my controller files like this.

[image]

And inside the `pom.xml` I have written the `lists`

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${client.target}</target>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    <bundlesList>
                        <list>se.danielmartensson.controller.maincontroller</list> Controller here
                    </bundlesList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>se.danielmartensson.controller.MainController</list> Java file here
                    </reflectionList>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But still I've got the error. I tried to copy over [this project](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloFXML) and rename the files. But it did not work well for me.

Can you understand what I'm am doing wrong here?

Comment: Judging by the error, it can't find the resource bundle. And given you don't have a `se/danielmartensson/controller/maincontroller.properties` (nor a `se/danielmartensson/controller/maincontroller_sv_SE.properties`), it can't load the bundle. The problem is not with loading your `maincontroller.fxml`, because it fails before that point.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel AH. So they are important too?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No, they are not important.

Comment: Your code loads a resource bundle, so that resource bundle has to exist, otherwise it fails with a `MissingResourceException` (which it does in your case). Otherwise use `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` instead of `FXMLLoader.load(URL, ResourceBundle)`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I removed the code and changed it to `        AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(MainController.class.getResource("maincontroller.fxml"));
` Now it's working. No know why `GluonHQ` put it there.